# Swift SpriteKit Delegate Pattern

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have been trying to learn how to use delegates recently and actually seem to understand it for the most part. However I have one problem.

I have 1 GameViewController, 1 StartScene and 1 MenuScene

In my GameViewController I have 2 methods that I would like to get called from MenuScene. So far I have been using NSNotification, which works fine but I am trying to use delegates.

So I have set up a protocol in MenuScene

```
 protocol MenuSceneDelegate {
 func gameOver()
 func showGameCenter()
}
```

I than referenced it like so

```
 var menuSceneDelegate: MenuSceneDelegate?
```

In GameViewController I added the MenuSceneDelegate at the top. All is very standard so far. However the main problem I have is that when I set the delegate in GameViewController like so

```
 let skView = view as! SKView!
    var scene = StartScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)

    scene.menuSceneDelegate = self   //Sets delegate to StartScene not MenuScene
```

it only applies to the StartScene. How can I set the GameViewController delegate from StartScene to MenuScene. Everything works fine if I would first present the MenuScene. However I present StartScene first and therefore I am trying to understand how I set the delegate to MenuScene.

I tried something like this below but it doesnt work and just doesnt seem right

```
 var menuScene = MenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
 menuScene.menuSceneDelegate = self
```

I would appreciate any help or support. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the solution is to set the delegate when I change from start scene to game scene, not in the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: That's a good question lol. This is such a old answer. I will update it later

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I have been climbing up and down the delegate/protocol and inheritance ladders for a couple of days. 2 steps up, 3 steps back, every time.

Comment: Hehe. It's not bad once you get the hang of it. I will update later

Comment: In regards to inheritance/subclassing check out this answer. Not sure its its helpful. I asked this last year http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486232/swift-multiple-level-scenes

Comment: I'm yet to really figure out the difference between super.init and self.init and their various needs. I just keep trying variations until one works.

Comment: Super.init is calling the superclass. In my example BaseScene

Comment: yeah, I kind of grasp the basics... but the mapping of initialisation in my head is a bit like a GPS during an electric storm.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at the basic Swift documentation from apple, they are very good. I did not do this when I started coding and it caused me alot of lost time. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html